# DateTime.Parse throwing string not recognized, I cannot see why

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I cannot understand why this is throwing "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

```
        string[] formats = {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt",
               "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss",
               "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt",
               "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm",
               "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm",
               "MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffff" };
    var delimit = line.Split(',');
    try
    {
        id = delimit[0];
        DateTime.TryParseExact(delimit[1].Trim(),formats,new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None, out openDate);
        delimit[5] = delimit[5].Replace("\"","");
        closedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(delimit[5].Trim(),formats,new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None);
        DateTime.TryParseExact(delimit[5].Trim(),formats,new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None, out closedDate);
        severity = delimit[7].Split('-').Last().Trim();
        state = delimit[6].Trim();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
```

The entry it throws on is : 
[image]

Comment: well the date format that you should use for "12/12/2012 13:20" is `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` and it seems it is missing from the `formats` array

Comment: @styx `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm`*

Comment: Note that `MM/dd` isn't necessary as `M/d` will match single-digit and double-digit days. The same goes for `hh`, `HH` and `mm`. I'm a little concerned what the expectation with formats such as `h:mm` is since we don't know if it's AM or PM.

Comment: @John how do u know if 12/12/2012 is `MM/dd/yyyy` or `dd/MM/yyyy` can be both

Comment: @styx Because every single one of OP's date formats is mid-endian.

Comment: Which one of the formats are you **expecting** it to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formats array should include the 24 hour time format.

Either `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` OR `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm` OR `M/d/yyyy HH:mm` OR `d/M/yyyy H:m` format can be used.

Please note that only you know whether your format is dd-MM-yyyy or MM-dd-yyyy as for both date and month places you have 12.

You can check the sample inputs to your code and depending on those you should choose the format carefully.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What about `M/d/yyy H:m`?

Comment: agreed, as long as we do not know how single digit dates / month number look like in the sample input, we cannot suggest the exact answer.  Updating the answer with this details.  Thanks @John

Comment: I meant that the single-character M, D, H, and m template characters match both single and double digits. See [this example](https://rextester.com/STQFB98651).